# Continuous variable in Cartopy

Tags: shapefile, cartopy

I have been trying for some time to plot shapefile polygons on a global map using Cartopy library. From [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58379841/continuous-color-map-on-cartopy), I have been trying to plot a continuous variable from an attribute called "ShIdx" but I get the error about 'value'. This field does not exist in my dataset but then I cannot figure out which value I should replace instead of it because I do not know how the .loc function is working.
There are two lines commented in ax.add_geometries() function, because neither of the two work.
Here is a fragment of my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
from cartopy.io import shapereader
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt     
from cartopy.io.shapereader import Reader
from cartopy.feature import ShapelyFeature

polygs = "./Samp_shp.shp"

df = gpd.read_file(polygs)

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(14, 10))

ax = plt.subplot(1, 1, 1, projection=ccrs.Robinson())

ax.coastlines()

reader = shapereader.Reader(polygs)
rectangles = reader.records()

cmap = matplotlib.cm.RdBu

for rectangle in rectangles:
    ax.add_geometries(rectangle.geometry, ccrs.PlateCarree(),
                      #facecolor = cm.jet(np.random.random(1)), edgecolor='k'
                      #facecolor = cmap(df.loc[rectangle.attributes['ShIdx'],'values'])
                     )
    
#ax.gridlines(crs=ccrs.PlateCarree (), draw_labels=True,
                  #linewidth=2, color='gray', alpha=0.5, linestyle='--')

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution. Maybe it is not the most suitable one. Please feel free to correct me.

```
    for rectangle in rectangles:
        ax.add_geometries(rectangle.geometry, 
        ccrs.PlateCarree(),
        cmap(df.loc[rectangle.attributes['ShIdx']))
```

This was my problem and from here I have been looking at different resources to create a nice map using cartopy and matplotlib.